# How to get images from the iPad library

Tags: image, ipad, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any approach to get images from the iPad library without using an embedded UIImagePicker controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Assets Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Assets Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html), however it's only available since version 4.0.